# Migrate Digital Ocean Droplet to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, digital-ocean, droplet

Is it possible to migrate a Digital Ocean Droplet to Amazon EC2?

I tried to found the relevant solution on google, but unfortunately I couldn't get.